# Woocommerce won't load javascript

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a WooCommerce website and right now I'm making mobile version of the website.

If you visit website on mobile device the custom theme (I made from scratch) will load. (using Any Mobile Theme Switcher plugin)

My poblem is that WooCommerce won't load javascript files on mobile theme. Which is causing that:

-search bar is not working correctly

-orderby dropdown is not working at all

-at checkout page when switching payment method - box with descriptions wont change

Everything is working fine on desktop version.

Website SHOP URL: http://nectness.com/trgovina/

To view mobile version on chrome just inspect the website, toggle device mode, refresh and mobile version will show up.

Search bar should be exactly the same as on desktop version, everything else looks like it should, but it's not functioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! It was just a noobish mistake... I forgot to add wp_footer in mobile theme footer.php file.

If you are developing your own WP theme make sure to add wp_head and wp_footer in header.php and footer.php

Answer (score 0):

```
    I have check your http://nectness.com/trgovina/ site
    All functionality work in responsive (mobile view) but broke design broke in mobile view (responsive view)

    1) First change responsive view css for eight columns  class in header section 
      please remove width : 47% ; please giver width :100% for eight columns
    2) set responsive view css for footer-first,fc1i2,fc3,footer-last,footer-bottom copy
    i Hope you understand .No any issues in woocommerce functionality but design problem in mobile layout view (Responive view)

Not changes in Desktop css but write css in responsive css
ex.
@media screen and (min-width: 400px)  {here write css so changes look in mobile and tablet lanscape}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px)  {here write css so changes look in tablet }
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {here write css so changes look in big tablet }
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {...}
    Thanks 
    Maulik
```

Comment: Why should i edit desktop version CSS? Everything is working fine there

Comment: Not chnages in Desktop css but write css in responsive css
ex.

Comment: okay I understand what are your trying to tell me, but I think you don't understand my question...

Comment: EXAMPLE: [Desktop version](http://imgur.com/a/lpVu6), [Mobile version](http://imgur.com/a/hCRrs) (Imgur)